# How to make the footer be at the bottom of the screen?

Tags: css, reactjs

I currently have some code that runs fine but no matter what I do, I cannot get the footer to stick to the bottom of the screen. Is it possible for anyone who can come up with a quick solution for this to add it to jsx code?

```js
function Header() {
    return (
        <header>
            <nav className="nav">
                <img src="./react-logo.png" className="nav-logo" />
                <ul className="nav-items">
                    <li>Pricing</li>
                    <li>About</li>
                    <li>Contact</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    )
}

function Footer() {
    return (
        <footer>
            <small>© 2021 Ziroll development. All rights reserved.</small>
        </footer>
    )
}

function MainContent() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Reasons I'm excited to learn React</h1>
            <ol>
                <li>It's a popular library, so I'll be 
                able to fit in with the cool kids!</li>
                <li>I'm more likely to get a job as a developer
                if I know React</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    )
}

function Page() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Header />
            <MainContent />
            <Footer />
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Page />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

Comment: Beware of some of the answers below — especially those advocating `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`. Better to design a more robust layout, using something like Grid. For best answers, supply an actual HTML/CSS layout that people can help with. This is a CSS issue, so posting JS is of no use.

Comment: "...no matter what I do..." What did you do and what went wrong? Are you using any CSS?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with inline css like:

```
function Footer() {
    return (
        <footer style={{ position: 'fixed', width: '100%', left: 0, bottom: 0}}>
            <small>© 2021 Ziroll development. All rights reserved.</small>
        </footer>
    )
}
```

or create a css file:

```
//jsx file
import './css.css'

function Footer() {
    return (
        <footer className='footer'>
            <small>© 2021 Ziroll development. All rights reserved.</small>
        </footer>
    )
}


//css file
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Give the footer a position of absolute, bottom 0. See if it works. You can use inline-styles if you prefer it.

```js
function Footer() {
    return (
        <footer className="target-for-my-css">
            <small>© 2021 Ziroll development. All rights reserved.</small>
        </footer>
    )
}
```

```css
.target-for-my-css{
  position: "absolute";
  bottom: 0;
 }
```

Comment: ```position: "absolute";``` will make the footer overlap with other elements

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the bellow styles to your code and change the `dev` structure.

```
function ErrorExample() {
    return (
        <>
            <div style={{ minHeight: "100vh", marginBottom: "-50px" }}>
                <Header />
                <MainContent />

            </div>
            <Footer />
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
footer{
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

Try this one, it worked for me, because it won't matter the size of the other pages you add in between, the footer will stick at the bottom.